# How do you print a JTextField?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, printing, jtextfield

I have a simple java Netbeans GUI shopping app with a simple checkout. I want to print a JTextField` value (checkout price) as a bill ?

```
try {
    boolean complete = textComponent.print();
    if (complete) {
        /* show a success message  */
        ...
    } else {
        /*show a message indicating that printing was cancelled */
        ...
    }
} catch (PrinterException pe) {
    /* Printing failed, report to the user */
    ...
}
```

How can I change this code to achieve that?

Comment: `System.out.println(myTextField.getText());` Try reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

Comment: question is not clear. Try to edit it. Do you mean that you want to print the price in a bill as a report printing. If yes Try using iText and then print the created report.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get the value of the JTextField.

```
String text = textField.getText();
```